# SQL - Foreign Key Constraint Error with Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am Trying to update my table (product) columns - ProductID(FK) and ProductType(FK). These two column has relation with MProduct table's column MProductID(PK) and MProductType(PK).

I am trying to update

```
ProductID       ProductType
9999            11
9999            12
```

But I got the following error

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKHCR_MProduct".
The conflict occurred in database "XXXX", table "dbo.MProduct".
```

I checked with MProduct table, It has all the valid records for look up. I can not change my Table Structure.

I tried this Query too

```
Select ProductID,ProductType
from dbo.Product P
Left Join dbo.MProduct M on M.ProductID = P.ProductID
   and M.ProductType = P.ProductType
where M.ProductType is null
   and M.ProductID is null
```

and there is No Output, means there is No Null Data Inside the Look up table.

Comment: try `where M.ProductType is null OR M.ProductID is null` if it returns value

Comment: Can you provide the table schemas and formal FK definition?

Comment: @John -  I already try where condition....

Comment: @Philip- I dont know what u taking about? can you please explain it?

Comment: Change the `and` in your where clause to a `or`. Does it yield results?

Comment: @Dominic - Same result No Output....

Comment: If you post the table definitions (table and colum nnames, data type, nullability, etc.), the foreign key definition, and the actual update query your are actually running, we will have more to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all the possible scenarios, you are either trying to insert a `NULL` value in your table or a value that does not exist in the reference table.

Most of the time, it is because you are trying to insert the `NULL` value in the field.

Comment: I tried with this query and there is no null data Select ProductID,ProductType
from dbo.Product P
Left Join dbo.MProduct M on M.ProductID = P.ProductID
   and M.ProductType = P.ProductType
where M.ProductType is null
   and M.ProductID is null

Comment: I check all my data there is no NUll vale in bot the table, not even in the inserting data,too.

Comment: Then you are trying to insert a value which does not exists in the reference table.

Comment: the Value is there...MProduct is Master table which hv all data (Look up table) and Product table is control table, and Here I am trying to update the certain columns which already exist in look up table in same combination....

Comment: Can you add your update statement in the OP? Can you setup a SQL fiddle?